# Dropbox API in Error occurs

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

In Dropbox api, this error occurs:

> Warning: file_put_contents(dropbox/tokens/766tYP3FZu8IEv4d.token) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dropbox\dropboxupload.php on line 28
>
> Authentication requiredhttps://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=766tYP3FZu8IEv4d&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdropbox%2Fdropboxupload.php%3Fauth_callback%3D1

How can this error be solved?

Comment: You've done this: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api ?

Answer (score 0):

Errors are returned using standard HTTP error code syntax. Any additional info is included in the body of the return call, JSON-formatted. Error codes not listed here are in the REST API

Answer (score 0):

Create folder at root name "tokens" and try again

Answer (score 0):

warning is due to not having "tokens" folder in your dropbox directory at root level.

create one.

second Oauth doesnot work on a Local Machine .
try to Upload it on a server and try again .